# Selecting row in table and displaying details

Tags: knockout.js

When user clicks row I want to display data in inputs so it is editable (don't want editing in table)

Here is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/APzK8/

Like you can see two inputs work and two don't. I'd prefer to have only Selected property in ViewModel. In real code every Config will have 15-20 properties.

Also if you could help me selecting first Config on page load. I can click the row with javascript but it is ugly. I think it should be defined in viewmodel. Tried many things but nothing worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you would need to access the values by doing `Selected().Name` rather than `Selected.Name`.  So, you want to get the underlying value of selected and then access its `Name` property.

However, an easier/better way to do this is to use the `with` control-flow binding, which will protect you against null values (avoid having to write `Selected() ? Selected().Name : null` kind of statements).

It would look like:

```
<div data-bind="with: Selected">
        <label for="name">Selected.Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" data-bind="value: Name" />
        <label for="value">Selected.Value</label>
        <input type="text" id="value" data-bind="value: Value" />
        <input type="button" data-bind="click: $root.AddConfig" value="Add config" />
</div>
```

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/APzK8/2/

To select the first config, I just initialized `Selected` to the first value in `Configs`.

Comment: I voted for @RPNiemeyer 's answer. I'll also add that if you want to show the input boxes, even when no item has been selected (just leave them empty), then you can initialize your Selected object like this:                                                                       self.Selected = ko.observable(new Config());

Comment: I almost forgot to mention your row highlighting question. Here is RP's fiddle, updated to add row highlighting:  http://jsfiddle.net/APzK8/3/

Comment: @JohnPapa I think that is a perfectly realistic way to do the row highlighting.  I like to use a binding though, simply so that it can respond to programmatic changes to the selected item (for example, the initial item that is selected).  Maybe not necessary in many apps, just a preference of mine.  Several ways to do it.  Can do the comparison in the binding string like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/APzK8/5/ or add a computed observable like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/APzK8/6/

Comment: Agreed that binding is a better option. I don;t like the first fiddle that puts an expression in the binding ... I like to avoid those if I can as it puts logic in there that I prefer to be in javascript. However I do really like the computed technique shown in your second fiddle (no pun intended). That's the one I'd recommend. http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/APzK8/6

Comment: Yes, it just depends on your preference.  It is almost always possible to eliminate expressions from the bindings (generally by computed observables, custom bindings, or even event delegation), but something like `$data === $root.selectedItem()` is hardly logic in my mind, just ugly in the markup.

Comment: So in order to avoid Selected() ? Selected().Name : null which is very very ugly I have to create custom property? If I don't like with's behavior of hiding controls when nothing is selected.

Comment: @JohnPapa: I like the first comment. Didn't think of that :) It will let me eliminate those ugly Selected() ? ... stuff from html. I love it :)

Comment: About highlighting selected row. I didn't ask for it :) But I don't like any solution really. I think it should be done in JS and not use ViewModel. $data === $root.selectedItem() is ugly and Config receiving observable of it's parent is also not nice. I don't think Config should know about ViewModel.

Comment: @Peri - I noticed that you didn't ask for the highlighting, but just wanted to respond to the original suggestion.  If you don't like Config referencing the parent's observable, then there are a couple more options.  You can call a function on the viewModel that takes in an item and returns whether it is selected like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/APzK8/9/.  You could use a custom binding (many ways to write it) to simplify the syntax in the binding like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/APzK8/10/.  There is a pub/sub way that you could do it too.  Let me know if you aren't interested in it.

Comment: Here is a pub/sub sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/APzK8/11/.  Obviously, the "postbox" could live where ever you like and could be passed into the contructor functions.  It could be part of the ConfigsViewModel.

Comment: I like this: css: { selected: $root.isItemSelected($data). Thanks for all the responses. I will learn a lot from you in the future - questions coming ;)